# Use block content to get post ID in WP_Query loop

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I have made a plugin to save *Testimonials*. For this:

- I have a custom post type called *Testimonials*, under which *Testimonials* are saved.
- I have a custom block, which the user can put anywhere in the editor and a shortcode will be printed there. The user can specify which *Testimonial* to use by putting the ID of the *Testimonial* in the block editor.
- I have a custom shortcode, which will make sure it all looks on the page how it should be.
- On the page, a div with the output is shown; the div has the ID which is put in by the user in the editor.

Within the editor, in the custom block, the user can specify the ID of the *Testimonial* to show. Now, I want to use that ID within a WP_Query loop, so I can make sure that it will only produce the specified Testimonial.

I have been trying to get the div ID into a PHP variable. And I have been trying to get some Javascript-action to magically turn the ID into something with which I can make a PHP variable. Unfortunately, I am apparantly not proficient enough in either.

So, what I am simply trying to do is this:

```
<div id="123">
<?php $testimonial_ID = /* code to get parent div-ID into this variable, the ID is 123 */ ?>
<?php $test = new WP_query(array('post_type'=>'testimonials','posts_per_page'=>1,'p'=$testimonial_ID)); ?>

...

</div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You have a shortcode, that the user can put in an ID that will output a specific testimonial. What's the problem then? Isn't the shortcode outputting the testimonial already? What's the use of the `WP_Query` here? Do you have the shortcode written? What does your shortcode look like?

Comment: Yeah, why do you care about the div's ID? Isn't the user just entering `[testimonial id=456]`, and then your PHP is spitting out the HTML?

Comment: At the moment, the user is not entering `[testimonial id=456]`, it is just entering the id `456` in what is essentially a custom block. I guess taking that ID and putting it in the shortcode as `[testimonial id=456]` could solve it, but I am not sure how to get it from the custom block content to work as part of the shortcode. 

For your information: the persons who will use this website are not tech-savvy. Asking them to use the ID might already be quite a bit ask. That's why I am hoping to use the custom block, so it is simple and they don't need to write the shortcode themselves.

Comment: So to be clear: currently the shortcode is just `[testimonial]`. I have tried to get the ID from the custom block content into the shortcode, but I can't seem to get it to work.